# Matplotlib font_manager.py font finding error

Tags: fonts, python, matplotlib

On a Ubuntu 12.04 machine, whenever I plot something I get an error like:

> /usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/font_manager.py:1228:
>   UserWarning: findfont: Could not match :family=Bitstream Vera
>   Sans:style=normal:variant=normal:weight=medium:stretch=normal:size=x-large.
>   Returning /usr/share/matplotlib/mpl-data/fonts/ttf/cmb10.ttf

which I cannot find a solution to online. The following code reproduces the error

```
import pylab as plt
plt.plot(np.random.random((128)))
plt.title("This should be monospaced")
plt.savefig("/tmp/testfig.pdf")
```

and also the matplotlib self test gives this error:

```
python -c "import matplotlib as m ; m.test(verbosity=1)"
```

In [`~/.matplotlib/matplotlibrc`](http://matplotlib.org/users/customizing.html) I have:

```
font.family         : monospace
font.style          : normal
font.variant        : normal
font.weight         : medium
font.stretch        : normal
font.size           : 10.0
font.serif          : Palatino, Bitstream Vera Serif, New Century Schoolbook, Century Schoolbook L, Utopia, ITC Bookman, Bookman, Nimbus Roman No9 L, Times New Roman, Times, Charter, serif
font.sans-serif     : Helvetica, Bitstream Vera Sans, sans-serif
font.monospace      : Monaco, Ubuntu Mono Regular, Bitstream Vera Sans Mono, Andale Mono, Nimbus Mono L, Fixed, Terminal, monospace
```

Some things that do not solve the problem for me:

1. Delete files in `~/.matplotlib/` (i.e. `matplotlibrc`, `fontList.cache`, `tex.cache/`)
2. Change the `font.family` property in `~/.matplotlib/matplotlibrc`
3. Re-install matplotlib after an `apt-get purge`

The versions I use are:

- matplotlib 1.1.1~rc1+git20120423-0ubuntu1
- Python 2.7.3
- IPython 0.12.1
- Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: There is no such folder as `~/.matplotlib/` on Ubuntu 16.04 with matplotlib 2.2.3. Where are the cache files I should delete?

Answer (score 4):

After some fiddling around with font packages, the solution for me was installing the following packages:

```
libsys-cpu-perl pcf2bdf tex-gyre ttf-bitstream-vera tv-fonts xfonts-traditional
```

I'm not sure why this helps, so perhaps somebody can add some background as to why this helps. Hopefully this helps someone else.

Comment: +1, same problem on ubuntu 12.10 (with mpl in a virtualenv). solved with your answer. thanks.

Comment: It couldn't find the font. When you installed ttf-bitstream-vera, you installed the font that it wasn't finding.

Comment: @Timtro but then why does changing `font.family` not work? Or does it always try to resolve all font families when starting?

Comment: @Tim - Good question. The answer was perfectly clear to me six weeks ago when I replied, but I can't see why at the moment.

Answer (score 2):

`matplotlib` always uses its own set of fonts, independently of other fonts installed on the system.
On Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, these fonts are located in `/usr/share/matplotlib/mpl-data/fonts/`.

When calling a font in your code which is not available in this directory, `matplotlib` will first try to fall back to Bitstream Vera Sans. However, neither that font is available in `.../mpl-data/fonts/` on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS installations. Finally, `matplotlib` falls back to the `cmb10.ttf` font, which is available.

Installing system font packages as suggested above will not remedy this warning.

One can, however, add `rcParams['mathtext.fontset'] = 'cm'` to the code to avoid the multiple fallbacks and warnings.

Alternatively, specify a font which is present in `/usr/share/matplotlib/mpl-data/fonts/`.

Comment: Is there a way to add fonts to matplotlib? I tried soft-linking my ttf fonts to `/usr/share/matplotlib/mpl-data/fonts/ttf/` with no success.

Answer (score 2):

For me on OSX, my Python installation was in my home directory due to admin restrictions which caused font location confusion. I was able to get Helvetica working following these steps: 
http://blog.olgabotvinnik.com/blog/2012/11/15/2012-11-15-how-to-set-helvetica-as-the-default-sans-serif-font-in/

1. Download and install Fondu to convert Mac-Helvetica to ttf-Helvetica. With homebrew, this can be done with: `brew install fondu`.
2. Find Helvetica on your system. For me, it was `/System/Library/Fonts/Helvetica.dfont`
3. Find where matplotlib stores its data. Use `python import matplotlib; matplotlib.matplotlib_fname()` to print the directory.
4. Put the .ttf in: `your_matplotlib_dir/matplotlib/mpl-data/fonts/ttf` then `sudo fondu -show /System/Library/Fonts/Helvetica.dfont`
5. Edit your .matplotlibrc file. Copy the original .matplotlibrc file into a personal directory so it doesn’t get over written when updating matplotlib. `$ cp your_matplotlib_dir/matplotlib/mpl-data/matplotlibrc ~/.matplotlib/matplotlibrc`
6. Find the line: `#font.sans-serif     : Bitstream Vera Sans, Lucida Grande, Verdana, Geneva, Lucid, Arial, Helvetica, Avant Garde, sans-serif` then uncomment and move Helvetica to the front. `font.sans-serif     : Helvetica, Bitstream Vera Sans, Lucida Grande, Verdana, Geneva, Lucid, Arial, Helvetica, Avant Garde, sans-serif`

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.

Answer (score 0):

Probably it isn't loading your `matplotlibrc` config file.  Make sure it is in the right place.  [The documentation](http://matplotlib.org/users/customizing.html#customizing-matplotlib) lists several locations that are searched.  Try putting it in one of the locations described:

- the current working directory of the python process
- at `~/.config/matplotlib/matplotlibrc`

The latter actually did not work for me with debian 7, but neither does `~/.matplotlib/matplotlibrc`.